# Error : Not all elements of twList are of the same class, when I convert the tweets with all variables to dataframe

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, rtweet

I am using rtweet package in R to extract tweets of particular hashtag which basically needs appname,api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret.
So i have created an app in Twitter to get all the above details. And then I pass the above as follows

```
 twitter_token <- create_token(
        app = appname,
        consumer_key = api_key,
        consumer_secret = api_secret)
tweets <-search_tweets("#iPhone8", n=1000, include_rts = FALSE, type = "recent",lang = "en")
```

So this will basically extract tweets with 88 variables. Now I want to write these tweets to an excel file for further analysis.

And for that I am using the below code.

```
tweets.df <-twListToDF(tweets)
```

When I run this I am getting the following error.

```
Error in twListToDF(tweets) : 
  Not all elements of twList are of the same class
```

Just want to understand what could be the potential issue here.

Problem is I cannot put the exact code here as that needs my api key and all.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards,
Akash

Comment: `tweets` is already a data frame right? So why not do `write.csv(tweets, 'file/path/to/write)` ? Moreover, I do not see `twListToDF` function in `rtweet` package. As far as I can recall it was there in old `twitteR` package.

Comment: Thanks Ronak for quick reply. I am using twitteR for this function. When I try to write directly to csv, I get this error. Error in write.csv(tweets, file ='c:/Akash/Raw.csv', row.names = F )
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'

Comment: Can you check if any of the column is a list in `tweets` ? You need to `unlist` it first before writing it to csv I suppose.

Comment: and how do I check that ? There are 88 columns. So is there any way I can check it using commands ?

Comment: `sapply(tweets, class)` will give you all classes of all the columns.

Comment: Oh there are many list here.. e.g. Hastags column which will have data something like c("iphone8", "iphone", "apple") , so does that mean I will have to unlist all list columns and then export ? Also when I unlist, ideally it will create 3 records for each hashtag value ? I think there should be some other way to extract..  I am using this link to replicate. https://opensource.com/article/17/6/collecting-and-mapping-twitter-data-using-r

Comment: Are you sure you are using `rtweet` package? In that link they are using `twitteR` package.

Comment: I am using both, rtweet  to extract tweets and twitteR to convert this into dataframe. Otherwise it will throw error that this function doesn't exists.

Comment: you don't need `twListToDF` function. Open a fresh new session and load only `rtweet` package and use `search_tweets` function from that package. The output of that should be data frame.

Comment: no luck.. I tried again..

Comment: I think if we try to get the tweets of a particular user, then it will only have 16 variables and those does not include list and hence you are able to write it to csv. However here I am extracting tweets with a keyword which gives 88 variables including lists. But now when I tried to get tweets of a particular user also e.g. tweets <- userTimeline("realDonaldTrump", n=200) .. this gives another error Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) : 
  OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'

Answer (score 0):

You can **as** **well** use this

```
tweets.df <-as.data.frame(tweets)
```